# Inserting data from CSV into SQL (using Sql alchemy or SQL)

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

This is more about concepts than actual code as I've spent some time rolling through google and I'm unsure how to correctly frame my question. I'm after some reading areas, maybe with some specific suggestions if possible.

Basically I have a CSV with a lot of data in it, for example lets say the columns are:

```
PersonId, Username, FirstName, SecondName, Age, Location, City, FavouriteSport, FavouriteAnimal
```

And I have a legacy database where each the above columns are all in a relational DB format - so for example using the above columns we may have tables with the following columns:

```
PersonId, UserName, FirstName, Secondname

LocationId, Location, 

CityId, City

AnimalId, Animal

SportID, Sport

AgeId, Age

PersonId, LocationId, CityId, SportId, AnimalId, AgeId

... etc etc
```

How would I go about finding how to take my CSV and insert in/update the data into the series of tables that have relationships between them. In my mind I can't just split the CSV into the tables and then insert as it won't tie the related IDs together. Am I wrong here?

The PersonId is the name number in the CSV as it is in the DB so I can map the row to that person, but I just dont know how I can insert the data and maintain the ID numbers of other items while still being able to map this to the one PersonId.

Thank you very much for reading and apologies if this a noob question.

---

Updated slightly 13:29 - added in part about the PersonId being the same number in the CVS which maps to the same ID in the DB

Comment: That looks more like a data warehouse, rather than a relationship system, if you have a table of IDs (`PersonId, LocationId, CityId, SportId, AnimalId, AgeId`). You CSV, however, is appears to be missing the IDs, so you're going to have to map those to your data by something else, name? and hope there is no one with the same name in the fie (slim chance there won't be).

Comment: Thank you. I think my above example wasn't very great. Everything from the CSV would be attributable to a unique overall ID in the database. I'm more concerned with how I can have everything map to this ID across the tables when trying to add in/update data

Comment: Sample data, expected results (for both your CSV and database), and your attempt(s) will help us help you here.

Comment: Are you suggesting your relationships will fail between each table as the AutoIDs won't match up?

Comment: @RazorKillBen, that was what Im trying to find out mainly. If I've got a set of data in a CSV where the columns in a single row should go into seperate database tables (or match up to seperates tables), how I can I ensure that when I add PersonId 54's favourite animal and sport (because that part of the data is missing for example), how will I ensure it will be linked to the correct PersonID in other tables. I dont really know how to ask the question I'm looking for an answer to.

Comment: I think I've got you. Not sure how practical this is in Data Warehousing, but I usually get around this by assigning the IDs manually in the CSV and then remove the ID auto incriment on the tables. Upload the CSVs to the tables with the IDs and then re-apply the auto incriment constraint. You may want to check that this wouldn't destroy any existing data.